# How do I activate a hover on link with a touch in touch enabled devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css

With HTML like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="readmore">Read more</a>
```

Then CSS like this:

```
a {color:white;} a:hover {background-color:#000;}
```

How can I allow hover and link work on one tap on a touch enabled device? Also, is there any way to activate hover on first tap and then trigger link on second tap ?

[Jsiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mx03umkr/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to prevent the click on your link and trigger the redirection on doubleclick only.

Change the style of your `<a>` with the `focus` property

```js
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
})

$("a").dblclick(function(){
  var location = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log("redirection to :",location);
  window.location.href=location;
})
```

```css
a:focus{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">My link</a>
```

NB : The redirection is blocked in SO but this example is working